# sublime text 2: how to set up autoreplace

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is there a way in Sublime Text 2 to set up autoreplace, so that I can have the application automatically expand Coffescript shorthand into JS, i.e.:

`(args**)->`

automatically converts to

`function(args**){}`?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a snippet for this. Here is an example:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
function(args**){${1}}
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>(args**)-></tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

Then you can type `(args**)->`+<kbd>tab</kbd> and it is converted to `function(args**){}` where the cursor is set in between the curly brackets.

For more information see [Sublime Text Docs: Snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html)